# Creating an array field in the Django Database Model

Tags: python, arrays, django, database

Hey guys I'm creating a primitive social media app and I'm trying to create an array in my table that has a list of usernames that the user will be following so that their feed shows only posts from users that they are following.

How can I do this? Right now I only have integers and strings but what if I need an array or a data type that can store multiple values?

Here is my code.  I want "follows" to be the array (or multiple value) field.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
    follows = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=0)
    followers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: does anyone have a better solution? I'm not sure how to create all these tables and have them work together. Sounds too complex.  I'd rather just have a list or an array full of values.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) or an intermediary model where you can add created information:

models.py:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'follow_from_set', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'follow_to_set', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm not sure how this works.  How does this add many different fields?    I would rather just have an array than multiple tables.  I don't get how I would utilize the table this way.  can you tell me more?

Comment: for instance, I need to be able to print out all the posts from users that a user is following.  I don't think this table helps me do that.

Comment: Indeed, my answer is really short. I'll send the code in the next days.

Comment: In a hurry ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995388/create-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-django ? so you can check the code from Antonio Melé here : https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-3-by-Example/tree/master/Chapter06/bookmarks That's a basic social media with your features.